# remove comma and colon followed or preceded by word not with number

Tags: sed

I want to replace colon (:) and dot(.) which is coming with words, not with the number
as: 9:30 no need to remove
    3.40 no need to remove
   a boy: goes to school - need to remove the colon
   a boy: goes to school -need to remove the dot

please let me know how to write sed command to do this

Thanks

Comment: What about `a:1` or `2:b`?

Comment: no need to remove

Comment: *a boy: goes to school -need to remove the dot* - no dot there

Answer (score 0):

Perl's look-around assertions to the rescue:

```
echo $'1:2\n1.2\na:b\na.b\n1:a\nb:2\nc.3\n4.d\na: b\nc. d' \
| perl -pe 's/(?<=\D)[.:](?=\D)//'
```

- `(?<=\D)` = preceded by a non-digit
- `(?=\D)` = followed by a non-digit

Your specification is still unclear for cases like

```
2.
:3
```

Answer (score 0):

***sed*** approach:

```
s="9:30 a boy: goes to school 3.40 a boy. goes to school "
sed 's/\([A-Za-z]*\)[.:]\([[:space:]A-Za-z]\)/\1\2/g' <<< $s
```

The output:

```
9:30 a boy goes to school 3.40 a boy goes to school
```

---

`[A-Za-z]` - match alphabetic characters